# For the .NET ToolStripButton, can I have a multiple line "Text" property?

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a toolbar of images, and I want text labels underneath the images.  Where the text labels are multiple words, I'd like to stack the words vertically.    How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To elaborate on Paulo's answer:

You can't do the multiline at design time.  But at runtime you can set the .Text property of each ToolStripButton like this:

```
ToolStripButton1.Text = "This is " & ControlChars.CrLF & "a button."
```

That will give you the multi-line display for your text.

Answer (score 3):

Still no support in VS UI for this in 2019. But you could put this after InitializeComponent() in the constructor as a simple workaround:

```
foreach (ToolStripItem tsi in tsMain.Items)
{
  tsi.Text = tsi.Text.Replace("|", Environment.NewLine);
}
```

And use "|" as a placeholder for the newline in the designer.

Answer (score 2):

Although not supported by the VS UI, you can have a multiline label. Simply use CrLf to separate lines.